# Lost on how to find the largest price below the target value from a given menu

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to create a method called selectFood that takes the amount of money I have as a parameter, outputs the selections on the screen and returns the percentage tip I will be leaving rounded to one decimal place.

I have the possible costs without tip done through recursion but I need to compare them and find the larger one. Please help

```
public static void selectFood(double money){
    /*String[]menu={"Bandera Pizza Bread","Boston's Pizza Bread","Garlic Twist Bread","Single Order",
                "Sun-Dried Tomato Bruschetta","Three Cheese Toast","Double Order wings","Starter Size wings",
                "Cactus Nachos","Baked Ravioli Bites","Southwest Quesadilla"};
    */
    double[]itemCost={6.49,5.35,7.49,5.35,6.99,6.35,16.49,8.99,10.29,8.49,9.25};

    possibilities(itemCost.length,"",itemCost,money);

    //selectFood(n,itemCost,0);
}

public static void possibilities(int length,String sofar,double[]itemCost,double money){

    if(length==0){
        //selectFood(sofar,itemCost,money,0);
        float totCost=0;

        double target=money/1.15;
        double minTip=money-target;

        char[]sofarList=sofar.toCharArray();
        for(int i=0;i<sofarList.length;i++){
            if(sofarList[i]=='1'){
                totCost+=itemCost[i];
            }

        }
        if(totCost<target){
        System.out.println(totCost);
        }

    }
    else{
        possibilities(length-1,sofar+"0",itemCost,money);
        possibilities(length-1,sofar+"1",itemCost,money);
    }
}
```

Right now I get back

```
0.0
```

8.49
6.35
6.99
5.35
7.49
5.35
6.49

Comment: ps I cannot use lists.

Comment: So you want **one** item from the selection, that is the most expensive you can still buy? Or do you want the **combination** of items from the selection that is the most expensive you can still afford?

Comment: I would like to get back 8.49 overall so the first question is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the largest value below the target value, you need a variable to hold the current maximum in each iteration you are making thru recursion.

I changed the logic of your program to keep track of the current maximum value

```
public static void possibilities(int length,String sofar,double[]itemCost,double money){
    if(length==0){
        //selectFood(sofar,itemCost,money,0);
        float totCost=0;

        double target=money/1.15;
        double minTip=money-target;

        char[]sofarList=sofar.toCharArray();
        for(int i=0;i<sofarList.length;i++){
            if(sofarList[i]=='1'){
                totCost+=itemCost[i];
            }

        }
        if(totCost<target && totCost>max){
            max = totCost;
            System.out.println(totCost);
            for(int i=0;i<sofarList.length;i++){
                System.out.print(sofarList[i]);
            }   
            System.out.println("\n");
        }

    }
    else{
        possibilities(length-1,sofar+"0",itemCost,money);
        possibilities(length-1,sofar+"1",itemCost,money);
    }
}
```

and you need to declare the variable max as static inside your class

```
static double max=0;
```

I added print statement to show the maximum value chosen in each feasible iteration.

After the end of all iterations the maximum value is stored in the `max` variable and to keep track of the menu list we need to add one more static variable as given below

```
static String menulist=null;
```

and we need to assign the value inside the method possibilities

```
if(totCost<target && totCost>max){
            max = totCost;
            menulist = sofarList;
}
```

Comment: how would I change it to return only the highest maximum value?

Answer (score 0):

The trouble you probably have with your method (besides it being relatively hard to understand) is, that your method is not actually computing a value (well... not returning any at least), but it is printing something to `System.out`. Generally, your methods should **either** compute something **or** alter state (e.g., perform I/O), but not both.

A simple fix would be to store `totCost` in an instance variable instead of printing it. That is, you can change your lines:

```
if(totCost < target){
    System.out.println(totCost);
}
```

to

```
if(totCost < target && highestPrice < totCost){
    highestPrice = totCost;
}
```

where `highestPrice` is an instance variable. Now you can access `highestPrice` from the `selectFood` method.

Note that this is a hack rathar than a clean solution! Your code would be much cleaner if your `possibilities` method would return the value it computes as the regular return value.

Rethink how you would recursivly compute the cost:

- You are given a set (in your case, an array) of prices, and a budget.
- For each price you can either take the item and pay the price, or you can not take the item and keep the money
- If you have only one item in the list, the most expensive combination you can make is either `0`, if you cannot afford the item, or the value of the item, if you can.

The last point is your base-case (not considering that you could also have an empty array). So you have for a base case

```
double possibilities(double[] items, double money){
  if (items.length == 1 && items[0] < money / 1.15) return items[0]; else return 0;
```

A side note here: Don't put magic numbers (e.g., 1.15) in your code. They do not convey any meaning.

Now for the general case where `items.length>1`: We can either take the first item, or we can not take it. If we do take it, then we will have less money to spend on the remaining items. Also, we can only take it, if we can afford it, i.e., if `money>items[0]`. With the remaining money and the remaining items we call the method recursivly and take the bigger value.

```
if(items.length > 1)
  if (items[0] < money / 1.15) 
    double totCostWithItem0 = items[0] + possibilities(/* items[1 to length], money - items[0] */)
    double totCostWithoutItem0 = possibilities(/* items[1 to length], money */)
    return totCostWithItem0 > totCostWithoutItem0 ? totCostWithItem0 : totCostWithoutItem0; 
  else // cannot afford it
    return possibilities(/* items[1 to length], money */
```

Sorry for being so sloppy with the code here. Because you are working with arrays, you need to copy items 1 to length in a new array in order to pass it in the recursive call. Also... I am not quite sure what the division by 1.15 is supposed to do, so you may need to adjust the money you are recursively passing.